# Destiny the taken king

Tags: ps4, destiny

I bought destiny the taken king and the dark below and the house of wolves then I bought a ps4 and now I don't have the taken king and I lost the code how can get it back

Comment: Did you buy the Destiny DLC on PS3? I don't think owning it on PS3 automatically gives it to you on PS4 as well - you'll need to buy it again, unfortunately. I think there is a deal on buying Destiny: The Collection if you're upgrading from a PS3, but I'm not sure of the details.

Answer (score 3):

Like with many other cross-platform games, buying the game or dlc for it is not compatible with the next gen system. However like @Adeese said you have until January 2017 to get an upgrade at [Bungie's website](https://www.destinythegame.com/upgrade) for $40.